# Julia: Is there a short syntax for making all functions available @everywhere

Tags: macros, parallel-processing, julia

Suppose I have a smallish number of functions that I have defined in a cell in ijulia (I'm using JuliaBox).

I'd like to be able to call the main function in parallel n times. The annoyance is that the main makes calls to the dozen or so helper functions I have defined.

Do I have to put `@everywhere` in front of all of these helper functions, or is there some shorter syntax that would work?

e.g. is there a command that would share all functions defined at the global level to all of the processes? Or is there a way to share a list of functions (rather than putting @everywhere in the function declaration).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I want to do this in the notebook I usually wrap the entire cell containing helper functions in `@everywhere` like this:

```
@everywhere begin

... put functions we want to share across all processes here

end
```